# A question that has been retagged is listed as being edited.

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing tags causes questions to be  active](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/changing-tags-causes-questions-to-be-active)

As the tag is really metadata, a question should not be shown as edited simply because it has been retagged. This is really a different bug from [that one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/changing-tags-causes-questions-to-be-active), but I suspect that fixing this one would fix that one as well.

Comment: I think it is the same question.  I'm voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: Uh, I was pretty clear that I'm talking about different behavior here. I'm talking about changing the tags causes the "Edited by ..." to appear in the question when, in fact, the question has not been edited at all. Couple this with the inability of most people to see the edit history and most people do not know if it was really edited, or simply retagged. How does this seem like the same question to you?

Comment: I don't think that we need two threads for discussing what is, in essence, the same issue: if you retag, the system behaves as if you had edited.

Comment: @Jukka Suomela: It was the two distinct behaviors that I was attempting to highlight. At least one person considers this behavior not a bug, but a feature. After it was pointed out that the edit history can actually be viewed, this particular behavior seems less annoying than it did before. However, the resolution of this behavior seems to have no bearing on the other behavior (other than an implementation detail, perhaps).

Answer (score 4):

I don't consider this a bug, but a feature :) Tags are part of the question, as the text itself also is. In addition, being able to see how moderators change the tags of a question can be a valuable lesson about how questions should be tagged.

Comment: As I noted above, most people–for example, you right now–cannot see what the edit was. I fail to see how this is a valuable lesson for anyone. At current count, tex.se has 1006 users and of those 20 can see the edit history. I also disagree that tags are part of the question.

Comment: @TH. Everybody can see the edit history - even people without an SE account.

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, right you are. I never noticed that it was a link. The way I was looking at edits was by clicking the edit button.